# Stimulus.js call method defined in connect() lifecycle callback

Tags: javascript, stimulusjs

Im still learning stimulus.js and I'm trying to expand on the DriftingRuby episode on stimulusJS and FullCalendar.  In that tutorial the form submits a normal http put request and the page is reloaded.  I'd like to allow users to manage events using UJS/Stimulus and not requiring a page reload.

This is my calendar_controller.js

```
import { Controller} from "stimulus"
import { Calendar } from '@fullcalendar/core'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import Rails from '@rails/ujs'

export default class extends Controller {
    static targets = ["calendar", "modal", "start_time", "end_time"]

    connect() {
        let _this = this
        let calendar = new Calendar(this.calendarTarget, {
            events: '/admin/events.json',
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            navLinks: true,
            nowIndicator: true,
            headerToolbar: { center: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay' },
            plugins: [dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin,interactionPlugin],

            // this navigates to the day selected from month view -> day view
            navLinkDayClick: function(date, jsEvent) {
                calendar.changeView('timeGridDay', date);
            },

            // This method fires when we select a time slot, or range of slots.
            select: function(info) {

                _this.modalTarget.classList.add('active')
                _this.start_timeTarget.value = info.start
                _this.end_timeTarget.value = info.end
                
                if (info.allDay = true) {
                    _this.allDayTarget.setAttribute('checked', true)
                }

            },

            eventDrop: function (info) {
                let data = _this.data(info)
                Rails.ajax({
                    type: 'PUT',
                    url: info.event.url,
                    data: new URLSearchParams(data).toString()
                })
            },

            eventResize: function (info) {
                let data = _this.data(info)

                Rails.ajax({
                    type: 'Put',
                    url: info.event.url,
                    data: new URLSearchParams(data).toString()
                })
            },

            addEvent: function(info) {
                _this.addEvent( info )
            }
            
        })
        calendar.render()
    }

    createSuccess(event) {

        this.modalTarget.classList.remove('active')
        this.addEvent(event)

    }


    data(info) {
        return {
            "event[start_time]": info.event.start,
            "event[end_time]": info.event.end,
        }
    }
}
```

I need to call the `add_event` method inside connect() lifecycle callback. As I'm learning Stimulus.js Im having a hard time finding examples where someone is trying to do something similar.

Is it possible to call the `add_event` method from outside the connect() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the function outside of the connect() function and you can call it from any function (with a few caveats).

```
connect() {
  ...
  this.add_event(info)
}

other_function() {
  ...
  this.add_event(info)
}

add_event(info) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: thank you sam, I changed `let calendar = new Calendar(this.calendarTarget, {` to `this.calendar = new Calendar(this.calendarTarget, {` and I can now interact with it outside of connect(). Can you tell me if I missed this in the documentation somewhere?

Comment: There's an example [here](https://stimulus.hotwire.dev/handbook/managing-state). I'm sure I learned it from a GoRails video, though.